# CakePHP Console on Godaddy Hosting

Tags: php, linux, bash, cakephp

I have been struggling to get my CakePHP site working on a Godaddy "grid hosting" account. My cake app is setup is hosted from a subdirectory on the account, and can be accessed via a subdomain. I had to adjust my .htaccess files to get this working, and now I need to get the CakePHP console working in this environment.

I have the same cake application setup on an Ubuntu server which is hosted on Amazon's EC2 service. Basically a plain out of the box Ubuntu LAMP setup. The CakePHP console works as expected in this environment.

When I try to run the console on Godaddy I get the following message:

> CakePHP Console: This file has been loaded incorrectly and cannot
>   continue.Please make sure that /cake/console is in your system
>   path,and check the manual for the correct usage of this
>   command.(http://manual.cakephp.org/)

I've started to add in some debugging code in cake/console/cake.php to find out what's going on. On the godaddy site, when I echo out `print_r($this->args)` at line 183 I find the array is empty. When I do this on my Ubuntu EC2 instance I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/www.directory.sdcweb.org/htdocs/cake/console/cake.php
)
```

It looks like godaddy's command-line PHP isn't passing through the bash shell command line arguments. Does anybody have some advice as to how I might get the CakePHP console working on Godaddy?

The bash script which invokes the Cake shell contains the following

```
LIB=${0/%cake/}
APP=`pwd`

exec php -q ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"

exit;
```

I am thinking that modifying this script may solve the problem.

Comment: the command line arguments are not being passed in...i'm not sure the cause of this...AND at the top of cake.php there is a path to /usr/bin/php but this is located at /usr/local/bin/php on Godaddy. I can work around this probably.

Comment: well, register_argc_argv is set to Off, this is probably why the cmd line params are not being passed in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in the cake shell script (cake/console/cake) change

```
exec php -q ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

to

```
exec php -q -d register_argc_argv=1 ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

after this I found out that calling php like this happened to run the PHP 4 CLI. to fix this here is the final bash script that I am using to invoke PHP 5 on my shared Godaddy hosting

```
exec /web/cgi-bin/php5 -q -d register_argc_argv=1 ${LIB}cake.php -working "${APP}" "$@"
```

if you setup a php-based cron job through their hosting control panel, you will find the php command invoked is actually to this php5 executable.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind `register_argc_argv=1`? That would be great!

Comment: it's a way for PHP to declare "i'll look for incoming command line parameters". see: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-argc-argv

Answer (score 1):

"Please make sure that /cake/console is in your system path."

This is grid hosting so I'm assuming you have a .bashrc file which you can edit. First you need to know the absolute path to your cake sub-directory then use vim or nano to edit your .bashrc

PATH=$PATH:/absolute/path/to/cake/console

Then you can log out and log back in and you should be able to type cake bake from anywhere and it should fix the error your getting (run it from your app directory so it can find your database.php).

Failing a .bashrc file you can export the variable temporarily but you will have to type it every time you log in.

Comment: seems like my PATH is correct. when i echo PATH in the cmd line it looks correct, and i can run the cake command from any directory, always getting that "This file has been loaded incorrectly" message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think editing anything in the lib/cake is okay, since it will be gone with your first cake update.

Rather, I changed the `register_argc_argv` setting from the php.ini by adding the line:

```
register_argc_argv=On
```

All seems to work now with me.

Comment: This worked for me using WHM php.ini editor. I had updated to PHP7 and the directive was changed by the update. (Easy Apache 4).