# No output from Cake Bake on Bluehost

Tags: php, bash, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I've got two CakePHP sites on a single Bluehost account (shared hosting), and have been trying to bake with both, but whenever I execute the command, the terminal gives no output and hangs permanently until its aborted with Ctrl+C.

I'm certain the command to execute the script is correct, because I have both sites mirrored on a private VPS and both work flawlessly, and I've checked MD5s to make sure there weren't any errors while transferring them. I've also set permissions for the entire console folder to 777, but still nothing. Anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: What command are you executing? Perhaps you need the support of bluehost itself?

Comment: i've tried both `./Console/cake bake` from the app folder, as well as the equivalent from the root directory `/home1/b******i/public_html/admin.b***********s.com/app/Console/cake`

Comment: I take it baking is a code build phase? If so, it would be better to do this on a local machine where it can be debugged properly. Then commit the changed files to VCS and push them (or rsync them) to the remote server.

Comment: Try `php ./Console/cake bake`, assuming the hashbang is meant to call PHP. Also, what version of PHP does it need? Maybe you need to call it with `php5` instead?

Comment: I noticed that on some servers, you need to execute your cake commands different. This one works for me: first, make sure that you're on the app directory `/home1/b******i/public_html/admin.b***********s.com/app`. Then try running: `php ../Console/cake.php bake`

Comment: I've got new info, for some reason cake seems to be stuck in an infinite loop whenever its run, running the ./cake command for 5 seconds yeilded 174,540 errors in error_log, the same two repeating:
`[11-Jun-2014 14:02:20 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_splice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /onbi/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php on line 323
[11-Jun-2014 14:02:20 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /onbi/public_html/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php on line 319`

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito, tried this, returns the same error as described above

Comment: Try this guy's solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542649/cakephp-console-on-godaddy-hosting

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito Holy crap. that did it. Thanks :D

Comment: @user782161 Nice! Glad that helped :P.